# Loop though one tweet at a time Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops, jquery-animate

Im getting in a bit of a muddle with some jQuery im trying to put together. I am trying to loop through the first 5 tweets via a JSON dump within my app, with them then I would like to show one at a time in an animated loop..

My html

```
<div id="innerTwitter"> </div>
```

and the jQuery so far

```
var $container = $('#innerTwitter');

$.get('/feed', function(data) {
    $container.empty();
    $(data).slice(0,5).each(function(_, tweet) { // Grab first 5 Tweets
        var $tweet = $(document.createElement('p'));
        $tweet.text(tweet.text);
        $container.append($tweet);

        var ticker = function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
    $container.find('p:first').animate( {marginTop: '-90px'}, 500, function() {
    $(this).detach().removeAttr('style');
    });
    ticker();
  }, 10000);
  };
  ticker();
    });
}, 'json');
```

So at the moment this is showing 5 tweets at the same time then removing 1 at a time until none are left, after which nothing else is displayed.

Could anyone give me some pointers please

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. This will display each of the tweets in turn with fading in and out.

```
var container = $("#innerTwitter");

function showTweets(tweets) {
    var tweetPs = $.map(tweets, function (t) {
        return $('<p></p>').text(t.text).hide();
    });

    container.append(tweetPs);
    tweetPs[0].show();

    var currentIndex = 0;

    var nextTweet = function () {
        var nextIndex = currentIndex == tweets.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
        tweetPs[currentIndex].fadeOut(400, function () {
            tweetPs[nextIndex].fadeIn(400);
        });
        currentIndex = nextIndex;
    };

    setInterval(nextTweet, 2000);
}

showTweets([
    { text: "tweet1" },
    { text: "tweet2" },
    { text: "tweet3" },
    { text: "tweet4" },
    { text: "tweet5" },
]);
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Tx8hj/1/

Comment: oh hang on, how does this fit into my .get method to retrieve the JSON? tried integrating but not working

Comment: Just call showTweets in the body of the function you pass to $.get. You may need to tweak it to suit your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var container = $("#innerTwitter");

$.get('/feed', function(data) { showTweets($(data).slice(0,5)); }, 'json');

function showTweets(tweets) {
    container.empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        var tweet = $("<p>").text(tweets[i].text);
        tweet.hide();
        tweet.appendTo(container);
    }

    tweets = container.children();

    var showNext = function(index) {
        if (index < tweets.length)
            tweets.eq(index).fadeIn(400, function() { showNext(index + 1); });
    }

    showNext(0);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q8zXa/1/